# How to trim file name containing extra characters using shell commands

Tags: command-line, batch-rename

I have a list of thousand files which have filenames with `.txt.txt` appended twice, I want to remove the second `.txt` from the file. for eg.

`File1.txt.txt` is the original file.

I want to rename it to `File1.txt`

I cannot do it manually because there are thousand files.
I tried different combinations using `mv` command but got no luck. Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086502/rename-multiple-files-in-unix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the below `rename` command on the directory where `*.txt.txt` files are stored,

```
rename 's/\.txt$//' *.txt
```

It checks for the files ended with `.txt` if it find any then it removes the last `.txt` part.

**OR**

If the folder conatins files in both formats like `file.txt.txt` and `file.txt`, you could run the below command to remove the last `.txt` part from only the files which has the format `file.txt.txt`,

```
rename 's/\.txt$//' *.txt.txt
```